# Visual studio code git pull is always running git rebase

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

VSCODE is running git rebase everytime I need to pull a branch. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED with `git config pull.rebase false` this solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible to just unset it, since the default is "merge unless `pull.rebase` is `true`"

```
git config --unset pull.rebase
```

Comment: Both leads to the same result but using the default is not as clear and intuitive for understanding what is happening. Lacks of configuration can lead to unexpected behavior.